# Short-cut command for Bold face number

Tags: macros, amsmath, bold, renewcommand

I often use short-cut command for bold-face letter such as

```
\def\ba{\mathbf a}   \def\bA{\mathbf A}
\def\bb{\mathbf b}   \def\bB{\mathbf B}
...
```

which allow us to use $\bA$ instead of $\mathbb{A}$ which would be very handy.
Similarly, I try to use it for numbers (notice that LaTeX does not allow numbers in name, so we have to use the following method):

```
\renewcommand\b[1]{\mathbf #1}
```

but it just gives $\b0$ to

[image]

So is there way to use $\b0$ to $\b9$ as a command for boldface numbers? Of course that I know it can be solved if we use $\bf$ instead of $\b$, but I just want to know is there any way to solve fundamentally.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't* use `\def`: you risk to clobber important commands.

Use `\renewcommand` with *great* care. For instance, doing `\renewcommand{\b}{...}` exposes you to weird errors when bibliographies are being processed, if some item in the bibliography has a bar-under accent.

Now, after this prologue, let's look at what you did. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\b}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\b0$

\end{document}
```

produces a bolface 0, not a bar-under as in your picture. I obviously don't recommend doing it, for the reason explained above. But it's possible to define `\b` to do different things in text and math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewCommandCopy{\baccent}{\b}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\b}[1]{\ifmmode\mathbf{#1}\else\baccent{#1}\fi}%
}

\begin{document}

Math $\b0$ and text \b{0}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

But, for your own good, don't do it.

By the way, the correct syntax is `\mathbf{a}`, with braces. And `\bf` has been a deprecated command for about 30 years.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you very much!! It works!!I really appreciate it! Thanks!!